# Removing from an arraylist android

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an android game which involves a ship shooting enemies. I am trying to make it so that if the enemies are within a certain distance of the ammos, then the enemys remove themselves from the screen. I have attempted to do it and the code compiles, but i am unsure why the enemys arent being removed from the screen once been hit. Can anyone see anything wrong with the code below? Thankyou

```
for (TopEnemy i : newTopEnemy)
{
    for (int q = 0; q < ammo.length; q++)
    {
       float xsubs = i.enemyX - ammo[q].positionX;
       float ysubs = i.enemyY - ammo[q].positionY;
       float squared = (xsubs * xsubs) + (ysubs * ysubs);
       float distance = (float)Math.sqrt(squared);
       if (distance < 10.0)
       {
          newTopEnemy.remove(q);
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't it be `newTopEnemy.remove(i);` ? `q` looks like an index on `ammo`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Iteratore.remove`.

```
for (Iterator<TopEnemy> itr = intList2.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    TopEnemy enemy = itr.next();
    //code here 
    if (distance < 10.0) {
            itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: So it should look something like this?

'for (Iterator<TopEnemy> itr = intList2.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
  TopEnemy enemy = itr.next();
  for (TopEnemy i : newTopEnemy) {
   for (int q = 0; q < ammo.length; q++) {
    float xsubs = i.enemyX - ammo[q].positionX;
    float ysubs = i.enemyY - ammo[q].positionY;
    float squared = (xsubs * xsubs) + (ysubs * ysubs);
    float distance = (float) Math.sqrt(squared);
    if (distance < 10.0) {
     itr.remove();
     }
    }
   }
  }'

Comment: @user3426043 the iterator should be replaced by your for-each loop.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove from a list while using the foreach loop. You have to use an iterator to loop through the list and then remove using the remove method.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to Vlad answer that is not always a good ideea to remove an item while looping over a list like that. I would do it like this :

```
for (int i = newTopEnemy.size()-1;i>=0;i--) {
    TopEnemy enemy = newTopEnemy.get(i);
    for (int q = 0; q < ammo.length; q++) {
        float xsubs = enemy.enemyX - ammo[q].positionX;
        float ysubs = enemy.enemyY - ammo[q].positionY;
        float squared = (xsubs * xsubs) + (ysubs * ysubs);
        float distance = (float)Math.sqrt(squared);
        if (distance < 10.0) {
            newTopEnemy.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this way, if you are lucky you'll get an ArrayIndexOutBoundException